# Do I have to create x variable to be assign, so the sapply() can work?

Tags: r

Do I have to create x variable first?

```
root<-read.csv("rootstock.csv", header = T)
rs.group <-split(root[,2:5], root$rootstock)
rs.group 

rs.means <- sapply(rs.group, function(x) {
 apply(x, 2, mean)
}, simplify = "data.frame")
rs.means
```

output: There were 24 warnings (use warnings() to see them) and
the rs.mean output were also NA.

[what I do wrong to get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jipEU.png)

Comment: I don't think `sapply` knows what `simplify = "data.frame"` means, and you can simplify your code to `rs.means <- sapply(rs.group, colMeans,)`, but none of that will help with your issue. You should use `warnings()` to see what the actual warnings are. It would also help if you shared some of your data reproducibly, `dput(rs.group[1:2])` would let us examine your objects and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your code. We don't have your data, but it seems to be similar to the `iris` data frame that comes with R:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
iris.grp <- split(iris[, 1:4], iris[, 5])
iris.mns <- sapply(iris.grp, colMeans)
iris.mns
#              setosa versicolor virginica
# Sepal.Length  5.006      5.936     6.588
# Sepal.Width   3.428      2.770     2.974
# Petal.Length  1.462      4.260     5.552
# Petal.Width   0.246      1.326     2.026
```

For other statistics use:

```
iris.std <- sapply(iris.grp, apply, 2, sd)
# Equivalent to sapply(iris.grp, function(x) apply(x, 2, sd))
iris.std
#                 setosa versicolor virginica
# Sepal.Length 0.3524897  0.5161711 0.6358796
# Sepal.Width  0.3790644  0.3137983 0.3224966
# Petal.Length 0.1736640  0.4699110 0.5518947
# Petal.Width  0.1053856  0.1977527 0.2746501
```

Comment: I tried it with iris and it work but not with the rootstock dataset.

Comment: I even tried to follow this one which is the same but still not working out for me. https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/237544_04ae21294e4c444ab98d442eb8e84e09.html

Comment: I do not have access to the root.dat file. What do `str(root)` and `summary(root)` produce?

Comment: https://imgur.com/4ZlgWAR  https://imgur.com/IQWdB4J

Comment: A picture of the data listing is not useful. It does not provide any information on the data types.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ri_ihAAoQtKWn1Iu7q7Fcihqpe0FnADC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I got it fixed, thank you! I really appreciate your help.